# Publishing the Web API in to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have published the created ASP.NET WEb API in the FILE SYstem. And in the IIS I have created a website and linked the published application in the physical path. After creating the website I tried to encrypt the connection string using aspnet_regiis. Everything works fine in the current server.

So If want to create the website on different server. How will I be doing it. I tried to move the published folder local in to the server and tried creating the website referencing that as the physical path but when I browse through the website it returns some irrelevant data.

Is there any procedure for doing this.

Comment: what is that irrelevant data? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I am calling the endpoint as http://localhost:80/api/ProData?id='LG0481' it returns the File as ProStudyData.Json that I have set up in the Controller. But when I tried to create the website in the Test srver where there is not VS. if I call http://localhost:801/api/ProData?id='JW217T_LG0481' it returns ProData?id='JW217T_LG0481' which I am not able to open

Comment: You should specify the appName: `http://<serverName/localhost>/appName/api/ProData?id='xyz'`

Comment: I am not giving any in the DEV server. I am not creating any application in IIS instead just creating the website directly

Comment: So are you getting 404? what error are you facing?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the en point is not returning the dat what is it is supposed to. I get the data ProStudyData.Json from the DEV server back, but not on the TEST server instead returns a file named ProData?id='JW217T_LG0481' whatever I am giving in the URL in a file and it has nothing\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118651/discussion-between-din-and-trx).